# What is the legality and consequence of blocking one who submits a SAR?

Tags: gdpr, england-and-wales, any-jurisdiction, subject-access-request

Alice submits a subject access request to Bob via WhatsApp, Bob responds to this by blocking Alice, but otherwise ignores her. What is the legality and consequences of Bob’s response to her SAR?

Comment: Sadly Doesn’t address the blocking aspect

Comment: Did Bob list WhatsApp on the contact details in the privacy note?

Comment: Perhaps not, but SARs can be submitted by any media.